# Can I use WCF services for uploading and downloading?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on a media server project for school, and I've chosen the WCF approach for this. However I'm starting to wonder whether or not this is a good idea.

Is getting a WCF service to upload and download files a straightforward thing to do? By straightforward, I mean something that doesn't involve a lot of hacks or third party libraries. The WCF service will also be expected to stream both audio and video to its consumers/clients.

I should also mention that the WCF service in question is being hosted as a Windows Managed Service outside of the IIS.

This is sort of what I have in mind right now:

```
    [OperationContract]
    bool AddFile(byte[] filedata);
    [OperationContract]
    bool DeleteFile(int fileid);
    [OperationContract]
    byte[] GetFile(int fileid);
```

Comment: How to: Enable Streaming:: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

Comment: @Mitch : I'm going to deal with streaming afterwards. For now, I'd appreciate any advice on uploading and downloading. I've found a couple of sites with solutions to this, but most of them have some sort of a limitation to their approach. One approach, for example, would only work if the WCF service was started as a console application outside of IIS or Windows Service Management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the methods to take and return the `Stream` data type and make sure to configure your binding to use `TransferMode.Streamed`. Also make sure to be concious of the encoding you use on your binding. If you use `Text` all binary data will be base64 encoded which will bloat the size of all your requests/responses. If you use MTOM then large binary data like streams will be transferred outside the SOAP body as a separate entity of the HTTP body as pure, unencoded binary data. Binary encoding will obviously provide the most optimal transmission over the wire, however it is not a standard format, so interop with other, non-WCF stacks will not be possible. If you'r pure WCF, you can't beat the performance of binary message encoding though, so I highly recommend it or fallback to MTOM if you require interop.

Also, I've somewhat assumed thus far you are trying to do this within the realm of SOAP. If you're using REST then the XML vs. MTOM vs. Binary encoding would be alleviated because you could just send/receive a pure binary HTTP body with the appropriate content-type. All depends on what you're trying to do

Comment: For now, I just need the WCF service to be able to handle simple file transfers. Also, I don't really know much about REST. Should I be using that instead of SOAP?

Comment: What classifies as "simple"? Are you talking about files < 1MB in size? The point of using a Stream with Streaming mode is that, if you don't, the entire request/response must be buffered into memory before being dispatched/returned from yoru WCF service. Obviously if your messages are large in size this will not scale very well. As far as SOAP vs. REST, I won't really get into that here, but I highly recommend doing some reading on REST to see if it's a good fit for what you're trying to build with this service.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. The bit about the streams also makes a lot more sense now. So the stuff described in that article linked by Mitch Wheat is what I should be doing for this, right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

Comment: Just for the record, WCF does dispose the stream after it's finished with it, so you don't have to worry about leaving the stream hanging.  (You can verify by inheriting FileStream and overriding the Dispose method).